# Complex analysis with several variables

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation, several-complex-variables

My question is simple, there are plenty of books where you can read about complex analysis in several complex variables , but I can't find a source of exercises treating this part of complex analysis, any good books to recommend ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of exercises in Krantz' book *Function theory of several complex variables*.

For something freely accessible, you might like these [lecture notes](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.j.o.o.wiegerinck/edu/scv/scvboek.pdf) by Wiegerinck and Korevaar.

Answer (score 1):

Here another free source also available in cheap print version.

[Tasty Bits of Several Complex Variables](https://www.jirka.org/scv/)